# Can a bow get a non-bow enchantment?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible in minecraft to enchant a bow with an enchantment that was originally just for non-bows, such as looting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: **No**

Long answer: **No**, unless you have a [mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/881089-v100-ssp-enchantable-bows-v10/).

Comment: I like the difference between long/short.

Comment: Even that mod doesn't give things like looting. But it still looks cool.

Comment: can answers be updated because this isn't correct anymore

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. If you make an [Enchanted Book](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanted_Book) you can add a non-bow enchantment. If you are in Creative mode, you can enchant a bow with any enchantment; if you are in Survival mode, however, you may only enchant it with Unbreaking.

Comment: Would they take effect on the arrow launched or the bow used in meleé?

Comment: I think it depends. For example, if you tried Knockback instead of Punch on a bow, it would work on melee hit. Not certain about Looting though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy way to do it on Creative mode, or Survival mode. (No Mod's Required)

1: You get an anvil, and in the first slot put the bow, and in the second slot put the enchanted book of looting there. Then you should have a bow enchanted with looting now. (The Image is from my Minecraft.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it can happen because of glitches - I had a bow with looting 3, without any mods installed.

Comment: Did you enchant this bow, or get it from a skeleton?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. In survival you can't but in creative you can
There are 2 methods:

1. Anvil
   Place a bow with an enchanted book of any enchantment
2. Command Blocks(Or chat commands)
   you can use `/give` command in order to get items with any enchantments(And exceed maximum level of the enchantment).
   Example:
   `/give @p stick 1 0 {ench:[{id:0,lvl:4},{id:16,lvl:1},{id:51,lvl:2}]}`
   this command gives a stick with protection IV, Sharpness I, Infinity II.
   (for enchantment IDs, please see the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values#Enchantment_IDs) for more information.)